# SYNTAX: what is the correct way to do a forward declaration for a c function?

Tags: c, gcc, syntax

I am currently tasked with getting code from one device to run on another and have a snippet of the functionality which means I need to shut down or feed the interfaces that are not being fed due to the cutting out of this module. When trying to compile I'm running into a syntax error that baffles me.

In a `.h` file I found a forward declaration at global scope like this:

```
void INT_CODE_ATTR fatal_error (unsigned char error_module, unsigned short error_line);
```

Where `INT_CODE_ATTR`was not defined. Since I don't know what it could/should be I did this:

```
#define INT_CODE_ATTR
void INT_CODE_ATTR fatal_error (unsigned char error_module, unsigned short error_line);
```

This gave me the error:

> error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]

So I changed `;` to `{}` resulting in this error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

I thought it had to have something to do with `INT_CODE_ATTR` so I commented it out, but the error persists. Also the whole line is underlined (in Eclipse) and it tells me just: "Syntax Error".

Just to clarify, my last attempt at solving this looked like this:

```
#define INT_CODE_ATTR
void /*INT_CODE_ATTR*/ fatal_error (unsigned char error_module, unsigned short error_line) {}
```

Comment: What's on the line(s) immediately before the one you show us?  Possibly something missing a semicolon?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Just a couple of defines and a reinclude protection at the very beginning of the file. It is the first appearance of a forward declaration of a function.

Comment: Where did you find the `.h` file?  Does it include any other `.h` files?  If not, look at the other project you found it in.  The macro is either defined in that project's Makefile (or equivalent), or may be defined in another `.h` file that includes this one.  It's likely a compiler-specific keyword extension that's only meant to be used in certain cases, and left blank otherwise.  Your trick *should* have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code sniplet you gave works just fine. Nothing wrong there (once you defined INT_CODE_ATTR).

Run gcc -E or your compilers equivalent to see what the pre-processor makes out of your actual code. What the actual compiler gets is not what you wrote, something is messing up the input.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! If I'm reading it correctly, the pre-processor makes this out of it: ```void {}``` which would explain why it's missing something. I'm assuming there is a define somewhere that defines the function name as nothing resulting in this.

Comment: @veryBadProgrammer — It almost certainly means there's a macro `#define fatal_error(a, b) /* nothing */` that eliminates the function declaration.  Use `void INT_CODE_ATTR (fatal_error)(unsigned char m, unsigned short line);` to avoid the macro expansion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that was exactly the case. I'm not working on this alone and the colleague that might have been responsible for this is not at work today!

Comment: Add `#define fatal_error fatal_error` as first line in your source. Then see where the compiler complains about it being redefined. (unless it's protected with #ifndef)